# Flow Roll Back on Previous Button

Tags: rollback, flowscreen

I'm putting a flow together that creates a parent object before moving to a subflow to create a child object linked to that parent object. But the parent object is being created in the main flow prior to the subflow being kicked off so the parent ID can be sent and applied to the child's lookup.

So the parent object is inserted and the subflow starts. But then if the user clicks previous, all of the values get wiped out, but the object still exists since it was already inserted. And if they hit next, it creates a second version of the parent object and then uses this ID in the subflows.

Is there a way to rollback the parent object when the previous button is clicked? Or is there another reliable way to know whether the object already exists?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? short of disabling the previous button I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: Nothing yet - I did the same thing disabling the previous button.